# Clickable xaxis ticks in Flot with Categories

Tags: flot

I am using the categories plugin for Flot. I have the xaxis ticks. (The xaxis lists different Products.)  I want to make each xaxis tick clickable so that when you click on it, an alert is triggered with some information about that xaxis.

however, when I add a tickFormatter function, it is completely ignored. (I have a yaxis tickformatter function that works fine.)  I think this is because of the categories plugin.

Can anyone demonstrate the categories plugin an a tickFormatter function on the xaxis.

Comment: You are correct, using the categories plugin (or the ticks argument in the axis configuration - which is what the categories plugin is using) suppresses the `tickFormatter` function.  How are you triggering the click?  Are you doing something like `return '<div onclick="myFunc()">Category</div>'`?

Comment: I'm not able to trigger the click, so I was hoping for a way to do that.  I'll have to investigate the DOM and see if I can add that behavior separately.

Comment: @Mark  do you know what class is used for the xaxis with the categories plugin? I have tried to use .flot-x1-axis or .flot-x-axis, but that does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var ticks = $('.flot-x-axis > .flot-tick-label');
ticks.css({'z-index': 100, 'cursor': 'pointer'});
ticks.click(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Inspecting this sample [here](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/categories/index.html), the generated axis is:

```
<div class="flot-x-axis flot-x1-axis xAxis x1Axis" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; display: block;">
    <div class="flot-tick-label tickLabel" style="position: absolute; max-width: 136px; top: 395px; left: 49px; text-align: center;">January</div>
    ...
```

I tried the above code on that page and it works.

**EDITS**

When using the [flot-tickrotor plugin](https://github.com/markrcote/flot-tickrotor) the labels are not divs but are "written" on the canvas.  Try this instead:

```
$("#chart").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
  var x = chart.getXAxes()[0];
  var y = chart.getYAxes()[0];
  if (pos.y < y.min) { // make sure user is clicking in XAxis
    alert(x.rotatedTicks[Math.round(pos.x)].label);
  }
});
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gy6wamN9fVM9L1GU4xKh?p=preview).

Comment: There do not seem to be any elements that match '.flot-x-axis > .flot-tick-label' when I use categories.

Comment: thanks for your patience.  Turns out I was using the jquery plugin to allow ticks to be rotated, and then removes the individual flot divs.  Now I can see what you are talking about.  Will need to figure out another way to rotate the ticks and get this functionality.

Comment: One thing I have noticed with the chart.getXAxes() solution is that almost anywhere I click in the chart, it triggers the alert.It's not merely click directly on the label. If I have a line chart with points in the lines and add a point click event on those, when I click on a point, I get 2 alerts, one from the xaxis the other from the point.  With the non-canvas method (where there is no rotation), you have to click directly on the label.

Comment: @MarkSalamon, yes, error on my part, didn't think it through all the way, see updates.

Comment: awesome, again.  I owe you.